# dynamic options list based on the previous select box value

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a webform. I want the second select box values to be loaded based on the 1st select box value. And these values should be loaded from DB table. Please let me know which hook i need to use and how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module.

Comment: @Hierarchical Select - It does not exactly match my requirement. Its not dynamic dropdown.

Comment: hierarchical select does not work with webform...