# How to use select option values in another select option value?

Tags: forms, webforms

I am using a webform module, where I have a select field with two values

> A|Animals
>   B|Birds

I am going to use another select field with some values like this

> A|Elephant
>   B|Tiger
>   C|Lion
>   D|Eagle
>   E|Parrot
>   F|Sparrow

Now I want first three options belongs to Animal category and next three belongs to Bird category (these two are another select option values). How can I select option values belongs to another select option value in webform?

**Note: 
1. The first select field with two values(Animals and Birds) will be hidden from user. Users will not see this select field. This is visible only to admin. This I will take care in css.
2.  I do not want to use `<Group Name>` since I want to put the select option values in another select option value.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamic options list based on the previous select box value](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17975/dynamic-options-list-based-on-the-previous-select-box-value)

Comment: @AnilSagar Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. But can you please let me know how do I use Hierarchical select module for a webform module?