# How to use Hierarchial Select Module for select field's of webform module?

Tags: webforms, taxonomy-terms

Answer is to use Hierarchial select module for [dynamic options list based on the previous select box value](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17975/dynamic-options-list-based-on-the-previous-select-box-value)

*How do I use Hierarchial select module in my webform module for select fields?*

Answer (score 1):

Seems like webform doesn't support [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module...

You can use [Webform Conditional](https://drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) module to create dependent fields...

Project page says

> This modules enhances the existing Conditional Rules of the Webform
>   Module. It adds the ability to make components dependent on select
>   components(i.e. listboxes, radio buttons, and checkboxes) that appear
>   on the same page.

Comment: Webform conditional module does not do what I want. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/17975/dynamic-options-list-based-on-the-previous-select-box-value